# Emacs on "software hatelist". What does he mean with. "Lacks controlled cross-module code/data protection."

Tags: emacs

Simply curious. (I use Emacs for Scheme and nothing more). 
Found [this](http://dottedmag.net/hate-list/) on a programmers *"software hatelist"*

Quote: ***Emacs. Lacks controlled cross-module code/data protection.***

I don't understand what this means, I would like someone to **come up with a brief explanation for me**. I probably only need a short explanation.

Comment: Given the shallowness of the criticism on that page, I doubt anyone other than the author really knows what he meant. Speculating here probably isn't helpful.

Comment: Search for cross-module code/data protection on Google. If you don't find anything relevant then there is a good chance it's not something you should be bothered about.

Comment: @RedGrittyBrick. I partly agree with you. However. Since I am curious and strongly suspect that there might be emacs users who can answer, I will keep the qw here for a little more. Even if the answer is that he doesn't know what he's talking about and probably isn't talking about anything.

Comment: @Tom. Good suggestion. I definitely will! However, not now. Since I am not at home for the moment (my sister needs the computer 'now').

Comment: @r4 What he means, basically, is "no namespaces and no lexical scope". The former criticism is justified, if not terribly meaningful in practice due to strong naming conventions; strong namespace enforcement, like Java, is largely a means of limiting the damage lousy programmers can do. The latter criticism loses punch in light of Emacs 24's introduction of optional lexical scope -- sure, "existing code does not use newly-introduced lexical scopes", but it doesn't need to, either; if it did, it wouldn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what he means is there is no way to prevent some "package" (which is defined very loosely in Emacs) from changing another package in (harmful?) ways.  So for example, `ruby-mode` could change the values of `python-mode` functions and variables thereby making `python-mode` misbehave.  This is in some ways unfortunate, but it's also very handy to have a package, say `ruby-mode+` which changes a few things about `ruby-mode` to be more like the user wants.